# Google Compute Engine VM instance start up failed

Tags: google-compute-engine

After upgrading from free trial, I am trying to start up my VM instance. I got this error:

> Starting VM instance "server3" failed. Error: The default network interface [nic0] is frozen.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What did the vendor say?

Comment: did not get response from GCP tell now

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose Google Compute Engine VM startup, since you cannot yet SSH or RDP into it, use serial port access.

As I wrote in [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27746205/3618671), you can use any of the following methods:

> - Web UI via [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) – on the instance detail page, scroll to the bottom of the page and expand the console output view
> - CLI via [`gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output)
> - API via [`getSerialPortOutput`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/getSerialPortOutput)

In addition, you can also enable read/write access via [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to enable you to interactively debug the issue:

> ```
> gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] \
>     --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
> ```

and then either connect to it using Google Cloud Console or `gcloud` command as described on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

Answer (score 1):

Known [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/%22The$20default$20network$20interface$20[nic0]$20is$20frozen%22$20%7Csort:relevance/gce-discussion/25YgtMktgr0/uHKhSI0TBAAJ) from Google side, check my post for workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246753/cant-start-compute-engine-after-upgrading-from-free-trial/44351827#44351827)